# Binomial law and efficiency

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

If a student goes through a multiple-choice exam with $20$ questions, each question having $5$ possible answers with only one of them being correct, what is the probability for the student to pass the exam (therefore getting a grade equal or greater than $10$) if each of her answers is totally random?

It seems rather simple as the law is $B(n,p)$ where $n=20$ and $p={1\over5}$.

My problem is that this law allows me to find $P(X=k)$ not $P(X\geq k)$.
With usual small values of $n$ it's not an issue as I just need to sum all the probabilities.

If I want, for instance, to know the probability of a grade strictly smaller than $3$, I do $P(X=0)+ P(X=1) +P(X=2)$. And if I want the probability to get a grade larger or equal than $3$, I do $1 - [P(X=0)+ P(X=1) +P(X=2)]$.
Fair enough.

But if I need to find the probability of a grade larger or equal to $10$, is my only option to do:

$$P(X\geq10) = P(X=10)+ P(X=11) +P(X=12)+P(X=13)+P(X=14)+P(X=15)+P(X=16)+P(X=17)+P(X=18)+P(X=19)+P(X=20)$$

Isn't there a quicker way I didn't think of (while only using binomial formulas)?

I searched the web but all the instances of that type (probability to pass a multiple-choice test) that I found are always limited to a very small amount of trials. So they always end up summing up one by one each probability. They don't say if there is a quicker method for larger amounts of trials.

PS: I tried to convert the binomial law to a normal one (using the expectation and standard deviation derived from the binomial law, and then converting it using the "T" formula) but it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Well, if the problem is that the expressions that you want to put in the calculator are so long, and if you also are familiar with summation, you could always use
$$
P(X\geq 10) = \sum_{k=10}^{20}P(X=k)
$$
This is much shorter to put in the calculator.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to help my daughter with her assignment here and she is supposed to make the calculations without using a scientific calculator. So I was wondering if there was some math formula to get there quicker as it seems odd that an assignment makes them go through such a long and tedious calculation for no reason.
It felt like there was something we were missing as usually, when a simple math problem takes too long on paper, it means there is something else we didn't think of (usually another formula available out there).
But your answer seems to suggest there isn't. Right ?

Comment: Without the calculator, she needs to go through a "combination * the probability of success ^ k * the probability of failure ^n-k".
And this, ten times in a row for each value of k.
We know it's correct but we wondered if there was a "magic" binomial formula without a calculator that makes it easier to compute. Or if transforming this as a Normal law would help (that's the only two laws they studied so far).

Comment: Which calculator specifically is it? And no, there is no shortcut formula that is exact. But some calculators may have tools that make it easier to do the same calculation with different values over and over.

Comment: Without a calculator? Really? I salute anyone who calculates ${20 \choose 10}$ without a calculator!

Comment: No calculator. Everything is supposed to be done by hand (which she did).
So ok, cool to know, that the method we use is correct and not unnecessarily tedious (on paper that is). Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread that. There is the normal approximation for a large number of trials as you said, but without a calculator that won't be useful either.

Comment: "If a student passes a multiple-choice exam..." then the probability for the student to pass the exam is 100%. Next!

Comment: Sorry about that. Language barrier. French talking guy struggling with English here. To "pass" in French means to "go through". It doesn't mean "to succeed". Wrong translation. My bad.